# What's the easiest way to produce an image strip from a set of files with the same height

Tags: gimp

I have a set of images (actually many sets but let's stick with one for now) that all have the same height in pixels and varying widths, I would like to combine them into one file with the images aligned into a horizontal strip and no overlaps or gaps.

I can do this manually of course by opening the set as layers then carefully moving them before flattening. I've also attempted to figure out how to use the "Image > Align Visible Layers" tool which sounds like the right thing but I haven't got it to work. Is there a quick way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Thou shalt use imagemagik

Comment: You're not wrong, looks like the `montage` command in imagemagick does what I want, but your comment is condescending. I would still like a solution in a GUI tool because it needs to be teachable to non-technical people.

Comment: What just designate a folder for images and let the batch run thats pretty good gui. But there are some guis for imagemagic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Gimp, you can easily align the tops, either with:

- The Align tool
- Using `View ➤ Snap to Canvas edges` or setup an horizontal guide and then move the layers to the edge/guide where they will snap.

To abut them horizontally, no solution out of the box, but using the [`arrange-layers` script](http://gimp-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml), you just position them roughly how you want them (the only important criteria is the left-right order of their left edge) and then call the script (`Image ➤ Arrange layers ➤ Space ➤ Horizontally`) (with a spacing of 0).